Negative percentages as dependent variable
I am analysing the effects of legal origin on the performance of firms within Canada and Quebec, and I'm in the process of gathering and cleaning the panel data as I was hoping to conduct both entity and time fixed effects models. My dependent variable for measuring firm performance is return on assets, but these values are usually negative percentages and can be quite large. Does that mean I can't carry out my analysis in this way?
Sorry if this is very basic stuff, I just find statistics quite difficult and was wondering if the direction I'm heading in is completely wrong.
Edit: The data I intend on using is made up of hundreds of companies and their return on assets (ROA) from 2018 to 2022. I also intend to control for firm size using the natural log of the firms' total assets, as well as controlling for their respective industries using dummy variables. Initially there was some extreme outliers, like -52,000%, which I have since filtered out using z-scores. But even after removing outliers, the ROA values range from -200% to 80%.

If you don't like a preponderance of negative percentages, why not just analyze the negatives of all returns?  But there may be an issue here, because large negative returns can have difficult distributions to analyze. You might want to analyze the actual returns, or log ratios, or something else: but you haven't offered any relevant information we could use to advise you.

Thank you very much for taking the time to respond, it really is greatly appreciated. I added some more information to the post above which I hope is more useful. To be honest, this question arose after a ChatGPT response stated that it was, 'essential to ensure that the percentage dependent variable is bounded between 0 and 100% to maintain the interpretability of the coefficients.'. After seeing this I started to overthink my entire project so far and therefore wanted to seek clarification on whether it would be feasible to continue with values like these.

Percents are troublesome in general and don't make a lot of sense (at least to me) when you try to incorporate negative values. Try modeling the amount of dollar returns themselves (whether positive or negative) with assets included as a predictor. You should fit assets (and other continuous predictors) flexibly, as it's unlikely that any simple single transformation will be adequate. Regression splines are a good choice for that.
